# Define a default array value from a class instance

Tags: c#

I have the following c# class

```
public class smallclass 
{
    public Vector3 var1 = new Vector3(1,2,3);
    public string var2 = "defaultval";

    public smallclass() 
    {
      var1 = new Vector3(11,22,33);
      var2 = "constructor";
    }
}
```

And I have another c# class

```
public class bigclass  
{
    public smallclass[] smallclasses;
}
```

Then somewhere else in my program, I increment smallclasses size with

```
smallclasses = new smallclass[3];
```

but I realize that the three elements are null...
is this correct behavior?

Allow me to clarify that I need that, whenever I resize the smallclasses array, its elements get automatically 'constructed'... I just don't know if such a thing can be done.

Differently than what I'd have expected, setting default values has no effect. Immediately after I resize the smallclasses array, the elements are null...

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps your use case would call for valuetypes: they are automatically initialized at the default value, always. They also have value semantics - which is usually ok for small types

Comment: @sehe do structs instantiate with predefined values? If for example I replace 'smallclass' with the corresponding struct, would my 'bigclass.smallclasses' array get populated automatically when I resize the array, instead of giving me null values?

Sorry for the ignorant questions.

Comment: @roamcel structs initialize with default values, but not user-defined default values, which you are not allowed to provide in a struct. Rather, they initialize with all fields set to zero (false for boolean fields and null for reference-type fields).

Comment: Thanks all for the great help.

Comment: structs are value type and can't be null. That's the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smallclasses = new smallclass[3];` is not resizing the array.  It is creating a new array.

Your array declaration (`public smallclass[] smallclasses;`) creates a field in the class `bigclass` whose initial value is `null`.  The statement `smallclasses = new smallclass[3];` creates a new array object and assigns a reference to that object to the field `smallclasses`.

Whenever you create a new array of a reference type (i.e., a class), all elements of the array are null.  This is expected behavior.  See section 1.8 of the C# specification, which says in part: "The new operator automatically initializes the elements of an array to their default value, which, for example, is zero for all numeric types and null for all reference types."

Comment: Thanks for the thorough clarification. It all makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, check out the [Array.Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) method. It will help you keep the values of the objects from the original array, when the newly sized array is created. From the linked article:

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies
>   elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old
>   array with the new one.

**Update based on comment:**

If you want the references in the array to refer to valid objects, you must allocate these objects and store them in the array. With a C# array you just have a reference to an array object. You still have to allocate the objects themselves and store their references into the array, if you want it to contain actual objects.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear, but I never actually initialize the values. I just declare smallclasses, and then assign a non-zero size to the array. My problem is that the values are null in such a case, and I'd expect -and need- that they be at 'smallclass' default values.

Comment: If this is what you want, you must explicitly initialize them to newly constructed instances.

Comment: So there's no such thing as an 'autoconstructor'? Then excuse me, but what are default values for?

Comment: @roamcel the so-called default values are actually field initializers.  These run when the object is constructed (with the `new` keyword).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for your array of objects to be automatically created for you. This is not how the language works. You need to construct each object individually, or in a loop.

If you do not initialize an array when you declare it, the members are initialized to the default initial value for the array type. For a reference type this is `null`.

Comment: This looks like I was trying to know:
so the fact that the values are null is actually correct, expected behavior? Or I am missing something in my declaration, or class methods?

Comment: You can use array initializer syntax to initialize your array with non-null instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [List of Smallclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)  instead of the smallclass[]. You can also do Array.Resize on arrays. But the list solution is better for performance.

Comment: Turns out this is a good suggestion for a possible refactoring. Thanks.